# What is the right configuration for hibernate4-maven-plugin to generate PostgreSQL schemas?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, maven, plugins, schema

I have been trying to get PostgreSQL schemas generated via hibernate4-maven-plugin that is created the same way I have done for MySQL but didn't find any resources.

This is the `MySQL` version of the maven plugin settings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
        <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</hibernateDialect>
        <username>testuser</username>
        <password>testpasswd</password>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
        <target>BOTH</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

After a little bit of twitching the parameters I got it to work with `PostgreSQL` too.

Below are the maven settings that worked like a charm for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
        <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect</hibernateDialect>
        <username>postgres</username>
        <password>postgres</password>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</url>
        <target>BOTH</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</plugin>
```